# Swift: Cancel a current Viewcontroller to Home Viewcontroller with animation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation, uiviewcontroller

I want user to cancel view controller and get back to home controller with animation like the facebook Group app.

I couldn't do it the storyboard the animation is just bad.

So I have two view controller :

**First** "home" > exactly like Facebook list of group
**Second** "The group itself" > when user ***hit "X" get he get back to The "first VC"/list of groups***

My Question How to do it in code with the same animation?

[image]